# How do you get the steadiest footage you can

Tags: camera

The title says it all, How do you get the steadiest footage you can? I'm creating a film/movie/video with my friends, we hired a screenwriter too. But, back to the point how do you?

## Please help me.

Comment: As written, your question is way too broad.  If you lock down all your shots on a tripod, the footage will be steady.  If you want to move the camera, you can attach it to a TechnoCrane and it will be steady.  A better way to get answers would be to show specific problems you are having with your footage and ask for help about that.

Comment: If you want a static shot, then a tripod is your best option. Apart of that, like dolly or tracking shots there are various equipment's available and it all depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: dont see what hiring a screenwriter is going to make a difference, you have various options depending on your shot and equipment. Tripods, Gimbals, Steadicam systems, dollys, cranes, the list goes on, you really need to research what each one does and what would be best for your shot that is being planned, there is no one system for everything.

Comment: you could always shoot everything on a tripod and add in camera shake after words to give it a more natural feel but again its all dependent on the shot, film style, etc

Comment: As Michael said, without more detail as to what you are trying to accomplish, this is not currently answerable.  There is an entire industry based around different ways to get stable footage and each approach has different advantages and disadvantages.  We can't give you a short and correct answer without knowing more specifics as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

I use a DJI Ronin MX 3 axis gimbal. Recently used it to film mountain bikes and was literally running along side them without any shake in the footage. Highly recommend it [image]